# Grep Match entire email multiple lines

Tags: bash, grep, match, data-processing

I have two files:

I have this fist file:

```
./j/n:jwillow@gmail.com:Test1
./n/o:nanofranky@list.ru:Test2
./j/r:franky@list.ru:Test2
./j/d:jdmq77@hotmail.com:Test3
./x/s:xsebastianmenendez@hotmail.com:Test4
./r/s:rsebastianmenendez@hotmail.com:Test5
./w/i:willow@gmail.com@gmail.com:Test6
```

And I want it to match this second file, but the whole email, not just the appearance of the word:

```
willow@gmail.com
franky@list.ru
jdmq77@hotmail.com
sebastianmenendez@hotmail.com
```

So I want the output to be:

```
./j/r:franky@list.ru:Test2
./j/d:jdmq77@hotmail.com:Test3
./w/i:willow@gmail.com@gmail.com:Test6
```

I try with `grep -f`, but, since the words appear in the email, I get all the lines of the first file, not just the ones that matches with the whole email.

Comment: Should the invalid email address `willow@gmail.com@gmail.com` really be present in file1 and match `willow@gmail.com` from file2? If so - what is your criteria for how to match an email address from file2 to the strings between `:`s in file1?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `-w` argument.

```
grep -w 'willow@gmail.com' file.txt
```

Output:

```
./w/i:willow@gmail.com@gmail.com:Test6
```

Bash script example to compare two files:

```
#!/bin/bash

strings_file="search_for.txt"
input_file="in.txt"

grep -w -F -f "$strings_file" "$input_file"
```

Comment: That would say jim.bob@gmail.com in the 1st file is matched by bob@gmail.com in the 2nd file. You can't use -w like that because email addresses don't only contain word constituent characters.

Answer (score 3):

You may use:

grep -wFf second_file.txt first_file.txt

Here, `second_file.txt` is the file containing the email addresses you want to match, and `first_file.txt` is the file you want to search for matches in.
The `-w` option ensures that only whole words are matched, and the `-F` option treats the search pattern as a fixed string (not a regular expression though).

Comment: That would say jim.bob@gmail.com in the 1st file is matched by bob@gmail.com in the 2nd file. You can't use -w like that because email addresses don't only contain word constituent characters.

Answer (score 0):

This might be what you want, using any awk:

```
$ awk '
    NR == FNR { tgts[$1]; next }
    { email=$0; sub(/[^:]+:/,"",email); sub(/:[^:]+$/,"",email) }
    email in tgts
' file2 file1
./j/r:franky@list.ru:Test2
./j/d:jdmq77@hotmail.com:Test3
```

It doesn't produce the expected output because I think having the invalid email address `willow@gmail.com@gmail.com` present in file1 and match `willow@gmail.com` from file2 is probably a typo in the question.

Answer (score 0):

both does basically the same thing, with minor variation in syntax

- 1st one via `"short-circuit"` `boolean` `AND &&` and `OR ||`
- 2nd one is same concept but via the `if-(?)-then-(:)-else` ternary operator instead

> ```
> gawk     'FNR < NR && $2 in __ || __[$_]' FS=:
> mawk -F: 'FNR < NR  ? $2 in __  : __[$_]'
> ```

```
<( printf '%s'
       'willow@gmail.com
        franky@list.ru
        jdmq77@hotmail.com
        sebastianmenendez@hotmail.com' )
```

---

```
<( printf '%s' 
   './j/n:jwillow@gmail.com:Test1
    ./n/o:nanofranky@list.ru:Test2
    ./j/r:franky@list.ru:Test2
    ./j/d:jdmq77@hotmail.com:Test3
    ./x/s:xsebastianmenendez@hotmail.com:Test4
    ./r/s:rsebastianmenendez@hotmail.com:Test5
    ./w/i:willow@gmail.com:Test6' )
```

---

```
     1  ./j/r:franky@list.ru:Test2
     2  ./j/d:jdmq77@hotmail.com:Test3
     3  ./w/i:willow@gmail.com:Test6
```